# ClassNotFoundException: derby ClientDriver (Spring MVC + Hibernate JPA)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, derby, classnotfoundexception

I'm learning Spring MVC, and tried to connect to a database with hibernate.
The MVC part worked, and in a separate project, I also could connect and work with the Derby database. But when I tried to put the two together, I failed.

root cause:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/jdbc/ClientDriver
hu.pikk.controller.PikkController.test(PikkController.java:42)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219
```

I don't understand why this is, because I put in the maven file the derby dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.10.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And I also put the derbyclient.jar file to my classpath:

```
..Java\jdk1.7.0_45\db\lib\derbyclient.jar
```

If anyone has any ideas, why it cannot find the class, I would be pleased to know!
I tried to search google and stackoverflow for similar errors, but none of the answers were useful.

I tried to create an entitymanager in my controller class in different ways:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/","/test"},method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(ModelMap model) {
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ClientDriver driver = new ClientDriver();

//  factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("punit"); //Specified JDBC Driver org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver could not be loaded

//  manager = factory.createEntityManager();
//  HibernatePersistence hp = new HibernatePersistence();
//  factory = hp.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence.xml",null);
    if(factory!=null){
        manager = factory.createEntityManager();
    }else{
        System.out.println( "### FACTORY IS NULL ### ");
    }

    //manager.getTransaction().begin();
    //Employee first = manager.find(Employee.class, 1);
    //manager.getTransaction().commit();
    //model.addAttribute("employee", first);
    if(manager==null){
        model.addAttribute("message", "Persistence manager is NULL");
    }else{
        model.addAttribute("message", "Persistence manager is not NULL! Hurray!");
    }

    return "test";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need the dependency for the derby client

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
    <version>10.10.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You will also need to make sure it is available in your container. you may wish to follow a [spring tutorial for web MVC that covers data access](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/web/)

**EDIT**

I wouldn't mix dependency resolution. If you're using Maven just stick with it. It's typical to mark the dependency as `provided` as your container would have the jar deployed as part of it's setup. For example, if your container is Tomcat you would place the jar in `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib`

You should also note that Spring provides Factory Beans to [create a Session Factory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-hibernate). The Session Factory in turn uses a Data Source to get it' Connections. By wiring your beans this way, Connection management becomes transparent and you can remove that code from your application.

In a typical n-tier application the specifics of data access implementation are encapsulated in a Repository/DAO layer which is then accessed from a Service layer. The Service layer captures business logic and co-ordinates data inputs/retrieval.

Your Controller should only be concerned with capturing/validating input before passing off to the Service layer, and returning output in a format expected by the client (HTML, JSON, XML, etc.)

Comment: Looks like adding this solved it, but I'm not sure why, because I added the derbyclient.jar to my build path earlier, and it didn't work. Ok, I have found out why: Putting the jar on the build path is not enough, (in eclipse), I had to add the jar into Project properties/Deployment assembly/Web deployment assembly.